# Pubkey of Token account?

Tags: spl-token, rust, api, js, publickey

Some API end points accept

```
<string> - Pubkey of Token account to query, as base-58 encoded string
```

as an account address.

What's "Pubkey of Token account"?

And how to get one **programmatically** given a wallet or account address? That is, how to do it in curl? Or at least in JS and Rust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token account for a given wallet address is simply a program-derived account consisting of the wallet address itself and the token mint.

This might help: https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account